# How do I remove the transition fade when motion blur is enabled in After Effects?

Tags: adobe-after-effects

[image: capture]

I don't want the fade of the hold keyframe when motion blur is enabled, how should I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Motion blur is a property of the layer itself and can't be keyframed on or off so there's not a whole lot you can do to stop it; if there is motion, it will blur.

Since your movement is happening in a single frame (i.e. keyframes are set to "hold"), what I would do is split the layer (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) and remove the keyframes before the split on the second layer (so there's no movement to blur on that layer)...

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change shutter angle to be anything lower than 180 and issue for hold frame blur should be fixed